# Link Woocommerce custom placeholder image to product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

On my woocommerce e-commerce page https://www.vattenliv.se/produkt-kategori/filter/ozon-och-proteinskimmer/ there are some products that does not have any product image set. Instead the custom placeholder image shows. Is there a way to make these placeholder images link to each product page, just like the other products?

The site uses the theme OceanpWP and Elementor page builder.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to do this is by using a child theme, to ovewrite the woocommerce function. This code in your child theme functions.php file should work.

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail')) {
    function woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail($size = 'shop_catalog', $deprecated1 = 0, $deprecated2 = 0) {
        global $post;
        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
            return '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $size).'</a>';
        }
        elseif(wc_placeholder_img_src()) {
            return '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.wc_placeholder_img( $size ).'</a>';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Unfortunately there seems to be something wrong with the code above. When I place it in my functions.php the site doesn´t load.

Comment: I edited the code above and I fixed it. There was some special invisible character. Try now and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks! Now the site works with the code, but the placeholder images are not clickable links.

Comment: I installed ocean wp theme to try solve the problem but it is more complicated than I thought. Sorry.